# Do any industry programming languages use Martin-Löf style identity types?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory

Most programming languages have some kind of type systems but are there any programming languages widely used outside of academia (in consumer-oriented tech, finance etc.) that have intensional identity types à la Martin-Löf?

Coq and Agda have identity types but they are primarily used in academia.